# Flyway migrations path not found

Tags: docker, flyway

So I am running flyway on docker container and flyway cannot locate my migrations folder.

I have defined it like this:

```
flyway.locations=filesystem:user/path/to/my/project/common/migrations/
```

Also changing the filepath produces the same error when running the docker container.

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Error message:

```
migrate_1  | WARNING: Flyway upgrade recommended: PostgreSQL 12.1 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
migrate_1  | WARNING: Skipping filesystem location:/user/path/to/my/project/common/migrations (not found)
```

Update: Changing the filepath doesn't work anymore. Running docker-compose up allways produces the same error with same filepath location.

Comment: You should post the error message as well.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the answer. Had a line on docker-compose.yml that stated the path too. You should not have it double as flyway.conf is designed to match the path. Removed that and flyway defaulted to default location /flyway6.1.4/sql.